# Can I share the same eclipse project on a SVN & a GIT repository simultaneously?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Can I share the same eclipse project on a SVN & a GIT repository simultaneously.

If yes then how ?

I am using Eclipse Indigo and have to share the same android(Java) project at 2 locations.

Unfortunately the configuration management can not be changed.

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a common issue for developers who are either moving from SVN to Git or simply want the functionality of both repositories. There are a number of blogs and articles available if you Google for [using git and svn together](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=using%20svn%20and%20git%20together).

You'll see all sorts of hints and tricks. The main thing to watch out for though is keeping SVN metadata files (everything in .svn folders) out of Git and vice versa.

Comment: Could you give a concrete solution for that instead of pointing at google ?

Comment: @AnthonyO.: The reason I posted a link to a Google search is that trying to expand this answer into a concrete solution would involve duplicating good work that has been done on a number of blogs. I would read through some of the entries that come up in that Google search to see which one might meet your needs.

Comment: So why not pointing at concrete ones? Because there are really plenty and I found nothing really helpful for that subject :( (I just want to have both GIT & SVN managed by my Eclipse... perhaps this is not the question here!)